# Sequelize JOIN query is throwing below error for the get request

Tags: reactjs, express, sequelize.js, react-hooks

My 'sequelize' JOIN query is throwing below error. I would like to create a JOIN query for the below columns from table for all of users for 'current date'. Sometime the `dailystatus` column may not have data for the current date.

Following are the columns from `user` and `availability` table:

`photo, position` from user table.

`dailystatus` from Availability table.

I am getting Request failed with status code 500 while giving the below query condition.

```
const userSchema = require('./server/models/user');
const availabilitySchema = require('./server/models/availability');

const UserModel = userSchema(sequelize, DataTypes);
const Availability = availabilitySchema(sequelize, DataTypes);
    


app.get('/service/availability', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    var today = moment().format('YYYY/MM/DD');
    const dailyStatus = await Availability.findAll({
      where: {
       dailystatus: ['in', 'out']
      },
     include: [{
       model: UserModel,
       attributes: ['photo', 'position'],
       where :{
         createdAt : today
       }
     }],
   });
    res.status(200).json({ dailyStatus });
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: e.message });
  }
  
});
```

`availability`

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    return sequelize.define('availability', {
        email: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
            allowNull: false
        
        },
        dailystatus: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
            allowNull: false
        },
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10).UNSIGNED,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        }
    
    },{
        tableName: 'availability'
    });
}
```

`user.js`

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    return sequelize.define('user', {
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(30),
            allowNull: false
        },
        email: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
            allowNull: false
        
        },
        phonenumber: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
    
        },
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10).UNSIGNED,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        password: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
            allowNull: false
        },
        privilege: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
        
        },
        photo: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(300),
        
        },
        position: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
        
        },
        dailystatus: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
        
        }
    }, {
        tableName: 'user'
    });
};
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: i think you might have error in your NewsModel where condition .

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo error, it should be `UserModel `

Comment: you'r facing still any error ?

Comment: yes still facing error,   if i give just give this query alone I am getting data from Availability table.. `const dailyStatus = await Availability.findAll({
      where: {
        dailystatus: ['in', 'out']
      }
    });`

Comment: But the above one in question throws error,

Comment: http://localhost:8000/service/availability 500 (Internal Server Error)
Availability.js:33 Error: Request failed with status code 500

Comment: @VyasArpit  Have you got any thoughts where the issue it would be ?

Comment: checking now . :)

Comment: please share your association for Availability & User model .

Comment: I find out more error details from n/w tab >> {"message":"user is not associated to availability!"}

Comment: yeah you ,might have problem in your association .please share it with me so i can debug it.

Comment: I have updated the User and Availability models details in question

Comment: okay got it . wait for 2 min i'll ans you. i got your problem .

Answer (score 0):

Association in Availability model can be like :
'use strict';

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const availability = sequelize.define('availability', {
        email: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
            allowNull: false

        },
        dailystatus: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
            allowNull: false
        },
        user_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(18)
        },
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10).UNSIGNED,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        }
    }, {
        tableName: 'availability'
    });
    availability.associate = function (models) {
        // associations can be defined here
        availability.belongsTo(models.user, {
            foreignKey: "user_id",
            onDelete: "CASCADE"
        });
    };
    return availability;
};
```

Association in User model can be like :

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const user = sequelize.define('user', {
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(30),
            allowNull: false
        },
        email: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
            allowNull: false

        },
        phonenumber: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(50),

        },
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10).UNSIGNED,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        password: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
            allowNull: false
        },
        privilege: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(100),

        },
        photo: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(300),

        },
        position: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(100),

        },
        dailystatus: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(50),

        }
    }, {
        tableName: 'user'
    });
    user.associate = function (models) {
        // associations can be defined here
        user.hasOne(models.availability, {
            foreignKey: "user_id",
            onDelete: "CASCADE"
        });
    };

    return user;
};
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216430/discussion-on-answer-by-vyas-arpit-sequelize-join-query-is-throwing-below-error).